# Говорил или говорили?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Как говорить правильнее - "Кого встречал я  —  каждый говорил мне одно и тоже." Или: "Кого встречал я  —  каждый говорили мне одно и тоже." Говорил или говорили? И как в этом предложении правильно расставить знаки препинания? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Со знаками все правильно, про тире сказали. **Каждый** - говорил, **все** бы говорили, это понятно.

Меня немного смущает построение фразы. В стилистически нейтральном тексте я бы не рекомендовал подобное построение. А в поэтизоврованном, риторическом, эпическом и проч. варианте слово "каждый" вообще лишнее.
"каждый, кого встречал я, говорил мне одно и то же" - нейтрально.
"кого встречал я - говорили мне одно и то же" - возвышенно.
("то же"- здесь раздельно!)
Как-то так.

Comment: Да, но слово "каждый" здесь главное, определяющее, говорящее о том, что все люди, даже не знакомые друг с другом, говорят одно и тоже. То есть в этом предложении я хотел бы сделать ударение на это слово, поэтому я хотел бы его оставить. Оно должно усиливать выражение. Прмвильно ли это?

Comment: Простите великодушно, я вчера явно не в духе был. Исправляюсь.
Во-первых, здесь не "тоже" а "то же". Это однозначно. Не заметил вчера. 
Во-вторых, я сомневаюсь, что тут уместно "каждый" - "одно и то же." "Каждый" может говорить одно", "и то же" - уже вряд ли. Это только личное мнение - и совсем для меня не очевидное, но в нацкорпусе есть только один весьма сомнительный пример обратного.
Что же качается усиления, то "каждый", конечно можно сохранить, но надо подумать как. 
*Кого ни встречал, каждый говорил одно и то же* - вот так, вроде,  лучше смотрится.

Comment: Кого ни встречал, каждый говорил одно и то же - вот так, вроде, получше смотрится. Хотя некоторый диссонанс "каждый" - "одно и то же" остаётся. 
~~~~ 
Я, кажется, понял... Без контекста "каждый говорил одно и то же" означает, что каждый из встеченных говорил одно и то же по отношению к себе (при каждой встрече, напрмер), но все вместе могли говорить соверщенно разные вещи. С этим надо как-то бороться. А там есть вообще расшифровка, что именно они говорили? Это сняло бы все вопросы. Кого ни встречал, каждый говорил одно и то же: Волга впадает в Каспийское море.

Answer (score 0):

*"Каждый"* - подлежащее в единственном числе, следовательно, сказуемое должно быть *"говорил"*.  
Тире в вашем предложении допустимо (оправдывается интонацией), но я бы поставил запятую. Остальное правильно написано.

Comment: Хотелось бы внести коррективы. Тире здесь соответствует известному правилу, сформулированному Розенталем: "...придаточные изъяснительные (а также условные ссоюзом ЛИ), стоящие перед главным предложением, отделяются от него не запятой, а тире: Кто весел - тот смеется"

Comment: Виктор, а почему поскромничали? Это по форме на ответ тянет. А по сути - на правильный ответ. Имхо.

Comment: Спасибо, Борис, за теплоту,с которой Вы написали эту фразу